# converting image to vector, resizing, in illustrator cs6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustration

A question about using adobe illustrator cs6...
Basically I want to be able to put images I’ve drawn (simple outline drawings.) in to illustrator, having scanned them on to my desktop, turn them in to vectors so as to be able to resize them to any scale, and then once I have scaled several different images, bring them on to one screen to create a composite image. 
I’m sure this is very simple if you know how, but I haven’t the slightest clue when i comes to illustrator!
Any help would be amazing.

Comment: That's quite a broad question you ask there. You might just want to Google something like 'illustrator trace a sketch' or somesuch. You're bound to find something useful. If you're having specific problems, return here by all means!

Comment: Agreed that this is very broad. I would start by searching for "vectorizing" to get comfortable with Illustrator. [We have a few questions already that might help](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22vectorize%22+is%3Aquestion). If you get stuck with a specific problem along the way, come post a new question with an image of what it is you're vectorizing as well as your attempt so far so we can do our best to help!

Answer (score 1):

Place the scanned image into Illustrator. Navigate to Window - Image Trace. This will open a new window with a few different options for tracing in Illustrator. Select your image and in the new window check the preview button in the lower left corner. I would recommend adjusting some of the options (advanced dropdown) in the new window to get the desired trace. They usually need a bit of tweaking to get the perfect trace. If you want to edit the trace, navigate to Object - Expand - Ok.

Image Trace can also be found under Object in the menu.

There are a number of ways to duplicate your object. Fastest way, I think, is ALT+Click and drag. To resize the object proportionally, hold shift when dragging a corner.

Scaling and duplicating your object can be done a number of ways. It sounds as though you want to have a multi-layer effect. Select you object navigate to Object - Transform - Transform Each. Check the preview button, adjust to your desired size and then select copy. This will create a new object with the effects you chose. After you perform this on the first object, you can press Ctrl+D or Cmd+D to duplicate it again and again etc. This method is great for generating a number of copies.

Comment: I would like to add that, while image trace does trace your edges, as a manual illustrator such as yourself, you will not be happy with the results.  My suggestion is to learn the pen tool.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. Understanding the Pen tool is completely essential!